# connect to vpn via another port( change pptp client port)

Tags: vpn, pptp, port-forwarding

as you know pptp port is 1723 by default,know I forward port number 21 to 1723 on my CentOs VPN.

Know I wanna connect to my vpn (pptp) from port number 21.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change this within your client config:
The line looks like
remote 192.168.100.1

You can add the port after the ip address:

remote 192.168.100.1 21

Thats it.

Comment: What is this "client config" that you refer to? You seem to be referring to a configuration file, but neither the question or answer specifies where that would be. After reading https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VPNClient I looked in `/etc/ppp`. The page isn't very clear in distinguishing client/server config though. Would it also be possible to do this via the GUI? If not, what file is this you refer to?